# Multiple data sources with spring data - need to set the property continueOnError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I am using two datasources in spring boot with spring data.
There is an option to set the property through property file `spring.datasource.continueOnError=true`

My requirement is to set this property for only one datasource and if the other one is down I need to make the application down.
How to set this property to the datasource that I need to skip the application is getting down ?
please find my datasource config

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean webNotifyEntityManager() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(webNotifyDataSource());
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(Constants.WEBNOTIFY_REPOSITORIES);
    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Primary
@Bean
public DataSource webNotifyDataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(driverClassName));
    dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(webNotifyUrl));
    dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(webNotifyUserName));
    dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(webNotifyPassword));
    return dataSource;
}

@Primary
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager webNotifyTransactionManager() {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(webNotifyEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `spring.datasource.primary.continueOnError=true`